# How do I re-activate Windows 7 after Windows has decided it is no longer genuine after an update?

Tags: windows-7, windows-activation

Windows just recently decided that it was no longer genuine and it keeps telling me that I need to re-activate. However, the dialog that pops up asking me if I want to make it genuine seems to crash or give a fatal error: 0xD000006. I've looked in Properties page for My Computer in the Windows Activation section and it simply says:

```
Status Not Available
Product ID Not Available
```

And there is no option to activate. I'd prefer to not have to reinstall Windows 7, so any leads would be greatly appreciated.

I've tried re-activating using `slui.exe` as suggested in the answers below, but when I do that I get the following error dialog.

[image]

I'm not quite sure what to do now and the thought of being on hold with Microsoft is not terribly appealing to me. Thanks.

Comment: Call MS, the wait times are usually pretty short.  Also, have you done a disk check, and/or tried a System Restore?

Comment: Thanks. I may have to bite the bullet on the call. Haven't done a disk check or system restore. Those a worth a shot too.

Answer (score 6):

Does the **Activate Windows** wizard (`slui.exe`) in the Control Panel work?

[image: activate]

[image: successful]

`slui.exe` has various options for activating a Windows license. You can try re-entering your product key by running `slui.exe 3`.

[image: product key]

**Or** you can run `slui.exe 4` to activate by phone.

[image: by phone]

Comment: Thanks. I did try this and I get an error dialog. I've updated the question to show the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

When Windows thinks it is not legitimate, it is complaining about some type of configuration abnormality.

You do not address this by Activating/Reactivating Windows. First you must figure out what triggered Windows to think it has been customized outside of standard configuration guidelines. Things that could cause this error: "Disable" the Windows Update Service or Windows Software Licensing Service (slsvc) or some other background service that doesn't usually have a user-manageable interface.

Restricting these background tasks permissions will also generate this error.  Major "time" fluctuations will too. For example,  shutting down, resetting the time back two years in the BIOS, and then restarting Windows might generate this error.

The fix is to run the "Microsoft Genuine Advantage" verification tool downloadable from Microsoft. It checks/verifies lots of "background/internal" settings and then clears the error state (assuming the problem was resolved)...